# Why does GC(Garbage collector) freezes current execution threads

Tags: c#-4.0, garbage-collection

I was reading Chapter 12: Garbage collection of `C# in a Nutshell` where in the section about `Concurrent and background collection` it says that

> The GC must freeze (block) your execution threads for periods during a
>   collection. This includes the entire period during which a Gen0 or
>   Gen1 collection takes place.

One thing I understand is that; probably it's trying to avoid any new memory allocation at that point of time.

Is there any other specific reason behind this - as why GC need to block currently executing thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN documentation claims that generations 0 and 1 are always performed [non-concurrently because they happen very fast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#concurrent_garbage_collection).

Performing a concurrent garbage collection pass will take longer than a non-concurrent one since access to data that is being processed must be synchronized between the GC thread and other threads. This adds overhead which probably outweighs the benefits of concurrency in gen 0 and 1 collections since they typically run very fast.

Beyond removing objects that are marked from memory, the GC also [tries to compact the heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#what_happens_during_a_garbage_collection) after performing a pass. This means that objects may move in memory as a result of a GC pass. For this reason a concurrent pass requires the extra overhead to synchronize data access between the GC thread and other threads of the process.

Comment: Miky, why did you removed your previous answer. Pls keep it. It makes total sense, +1 for the reasoning.

Comment: @Rahul - I've added that part back but I rephrased the answer to better reflect what was available on MSDN regarding this process. The whole article is worth reading!

Comment: Indeed, right now doing that only. Thanks for pointing to it.